# How to get cgcolor from nscolor with pattern image using swift?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nscolor, cgcolor

Here my line

```
NSView *myview
[self.myview.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"]].CGColor];
```

How to write these lines in  `swift language`

.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand beginning of your code (why `self.myview.layer` if `myview` is declared one line above), but rest should be something like this:

```
self.myview.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(patternImage:NSImage(named: "myImageName.png")!).CGColor
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, normally in my project its in .h file only. for your all understanding i typed above that line.

Comment: I have one more doubt, can you help me in that
Objective C ::     CALayer *previewViewLayer = [[self previewView] layer];

I tried Swift like this :: 
var previewViewLayer = CALayer()
previewViewLayer = self.previewView.layer

Here previewView is NSView, and self.previewView.layer getting correct value but it not assigning to previewViewLayer.

Comment: What about this?:

var previewViewLayer:CALayer
if ((self.previewView.layer) != nil) {
    previewViewLayer = self.previewView.layer!
}

Comment: No its giving Exception :: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: Didi you set "self.previewView.wantsLayer = true" ? and assign some layer to view "self.previewView.layer = anyLayer"?